# ORDER BY table structure instead of numerical

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

My current MsSQL query looks like this :

```
all =  'SELECT Master_Sub_Account , cAccountTypeDescription , Debit , Credit FROM [Kyle].[dbo].[PostGL] AS genLedger'\
                ' Inner JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[Accounts] '\
                'on Accounts.AccountLink = genLedger.AccountLink '\
                'Inner JOIN [Kyle].[dbo].[_etblGLAccountTypes] as AccountTypes '\
                'on Accounts.iAccountType = AccountTypes.idGLAccountType'\
                ' WHERE genLedger.AccountLink not in (161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,122)'\
                ' AND genLedger.TxDate > ?'\
                ' ORDER BY iAccountType'
```

I would need the ORDER BY `iAccountType` to show the order that the data is placed in the table , not numerical.

Currently the output looks like this **(see Account column)**:

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Remove django and python tags as this seems irrelevant

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `he order that the data is placed in the table` ?

Comment: There is no "order that the data is placed in the table". In SQL, tables are *unordered* collections of rows. If you wish to know when rows were inserted into the table, it's up to *you* to place data recording such details in appropriate column(s) within the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the attached screenshot, it is ordered by the Account column (ASC). Is that what you need? If yes than the `ASC` keyword what you have to use.

Here is an example:

```sql
create table #tmpTable (col1 varchar(10))

insert into #tmpTable
values ('3020>010')
 ,('2750>020')
 ,('1000>180')
 ,('1000>001')
 ,('3620>011')
 ,('3200')
 ,('3850')

 select col1
 from #tmpTable
 order by col1 asc

 drop table #tmpTable
```

the result must be:

```
1000>001
1000>180
2750>020
3020>010
3200
3620>011
3850
```